# Centos graphical installer format old disk

Tags: hard-drive, centos, format, centos-7

In the Centos graphical installer, i would like to format the whole disk and start from scratch, but it still keeps a rescue version from the previous os on the disk, how can i disable that and instead make it format the whole disk?

Comment: Converted to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format or Erase the disk before you install CentOS, there are plenty of free bootable utilities to do this. [Dban is one of them.](http://www.dban.org/) No need to erase the drive completely using dban, just let dban run for 15 minutes then power down, this will remove all formatting, now install CentOS